# libGDX client (server) client connection

Tags: java, sockets, libgdx, client-server, hole-punching

I am trying to create a multiplayer game.
I think there are three possible ways to do this:

```
1. Port Forwarding
```

Only a few people will open a port on their router.

```
2. UDP / TCP hole punching
```

This is verry ccomplicated and will not work with every router / NAT.

```
3. Relay Server
```

I think this is the easiest method to accomplish a multiplayer.
So my plan is to establish a socket connection to a PHP server which will also have a socket connection with the other player and passes the data.

At the time I have a client part and a test server part in Java:

```
SocketHints hints = new SocketHints();
Socket client = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, textfield.getText(), 9021, hints);
       try {
               client.getOutputStream().write((textfield2.getText() + "\n").getBytes());
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

And

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ServerSocketHints serverSocketHint = new ServerSocketHints();
            serverSocketHint.acceptTimeout = 0;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, 9021, serverSocketHint);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(null);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                try {
                    status += "Receiving message: \"" + buffer.readLine() + "\"\n\n";
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

How can I receive data from the socket connection from the client?

And is there maybe a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to make a socket server from PHP? I'm not recommending it. Try to use [kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet). It's a java Socket Client & Server with an easy way to use in Java.

If you want to make the server online, run the Kryonet Socket Server on your Server with available public IP.